# React Native TextInput: How to know index of character typed by user

Tags: react-native, onchange, textinput, onkeypress

In React Native TextInput, how can I know the index of typed character by user?

example: This is joe

If the user moves cursor after "is" word and types "This is not joe".

I want to know index of user typed characters " " then "n" and then "o" and then "t".

I do get what user typed in onKeyPress

```
const keyPressHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.nativeEvent.key + "Pressed");
    console.log(e.nativeEvent);
    setKeyPressed(e.nativeEvent.key);
  }

This is my TextInput field
<TextInput 
    {...props}
    style = {styles.textField}
    multiline = {true}
    textAlignVertical = 'top'
    placeholder = 'Enter your text'
    onChangeText={onChangeTextHandler}
    onChange = {onChangeHandler}
    onBlur={lostFocusHandler}
    onKeyPress = {keyPressHandler}
    value = {postText}
     />
```

I am writing a component where when a user types " @" i am showing a list of users to mention them in post, so I need to know the index of typed character and then need to know if there is space before typed character and then only to show users list.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a piece of state to hold the text input and then use an Effect to check the string each time the value changes for the @ symbol.

Something like:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react-native';

const MyTextInput = () => {
     const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

     useEffect(() => {
         if(value.indexOf('@') !== -1){
            const index = value.indexOf('@');
            ** Do Something **
         }
     }, [value]);

return (
     <TextInput 
          {...props}
          style = {styles.textField}
          multiline = {true}
          textAlignVertical = 'top'
          placeholder = 'Enter your text'
          onChangeText={setValue}
          onChange = {onChangeHandler}
          onBlur={lostFocusHandler}
          value={value}
          />
)
}
```

The reason I suggest the above method is that the onKeyPress function doesn't work for android hardware keyboards, whereas, the above method will work for everything.

The method above will also give you the index of `@` so that you can get the substring after it.

NOTE: The indexOf method will only look for the first @ in the string. A Regex might help for scenarios where the user can enter multiple @.

Answer (score 0):

onSelectionChange gives the cursor position. Start and end position is same as you move cursor around. If select something then it will differ/

```
 const selectionChangeHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("Selection change handler Start = " + e.nativeEvent.selection.start + "End =" + e.nativeEvent.selection.end);
    setCursorPosition(e.nativeEvent.selection);
  };

<TextInput 
    {...props}
    style = {styles.textField}
    multiline = {true}
    textAlignVertical = 'top'
    placeholder = 'Enter your text'
    onChangeText={onChangeTextHandler}
    onChange = {onChangeHandler}
    onBlur={lostFocusHandler}
    onKeyPress = {keyPressHandler}
    onSelectionChange = {selectionChangeHandler}
    selectTextOnFocus = {false}
    value = {postText}
    ref={postTextInputField}

     />
```